# Was wool packing a main task for medieval peasants?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, peasants, industry

In Europe/UK, would a main task for peasants/working classes been to pack wool?  And, if so, roughly what dates would this have been please?  What did the entire process involve from obtaining the wool from sheep to its sale as a finished product?

Comment: The middle-ages spans a thousand years (give or take) and farming evolved over that period, so you might want to narrow your date range a little. Shearing sheep generally happens once a year, so the process isn't going to be a significant part of any peasants occupation for more than a week or two.

Comment: I _always_ like questions that ask for economic analysis. [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786) (I'm not sure "working class" is a useful term for the medieval period).  There ought to be figures on the production of the wool industry by decade that would help you to narrow down the period. There ought to be analysis of the stages of wool production at various technology levels that would help you to refine the question. Good luck

Comment: Steve Bird and MCW - thank you so much for your informative replies.  Appreciated.

Comment: Wool was not really a finished product but part of a *sheep > fleece > wool > yarn > textile > clothing* chain.

Comment: Henry gives a basic breakdown of the steps. Wool packing would be taking the shorn wool and packing it into sacks for transport to whoever then spun the wool into yarn (thread). Spinning would be a very time consuming process followed by the weaving into cloth. Spinning wheels for producing yarn appear to have entered Europe from the Moslem world around the 13th century.
I suggest you read up first on wool production to get the stages and terms and then check to see how those stages were done in the middle ages and what time they may have taken.

Comment: Henry and Damion Keeling - thank you so much for your informative replies; really helpful so thank you both.